# minimum possible array permutation problem

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation

In this problem , I have been given an array , and a binary matrix ( matrix consisting of  0 and 1 only ) , i and j value can be thought of index of array elment and if matrix[i][j]==1 then we can swap a[i] and a[j] , now what I have to do is to  get the minimum possible permutation using all those one in matrix in any order, 
this is initial array suppose
n = 5 size array is there

4 2 1 5 3

now this is given matrix, which is nXn

00100

00011

10010

01101

01010

using all those one,we can get minimum possible permutation like this
(using 1-based indexing to explain)

4 2 1 5 3 initial

we do (p1<->p3)

we get,1 2 4 5 3

now we do (p4<->p5)

we get, 1 2 4 3 5

and now we do (p3<->p4)

we get,
1 2 3 4 5

this is minimum possible we can get using one's

I can think of brute force but that would of course give TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED, so I am wondering how to approach this problem in a better way.

for more detail, here is the link to the problem, https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/pre-placement-coding-test/challenges/smallest-permutation/problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would interpret "possible swaps" matrix as graph then you could figure out, that in every [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) you could rearrange numbers in any order you want.

So the solution is to find all components and sort numbers independently in every one.

```
# read input
n = int(input())
p = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = [list(map(int, input().strip())) for i in range(n)]


# find components
color = [None] * n
def dfs(v, cl):
    if color[v] is not None:
        return
    color[v] = cl
    for u in range(n):
        if a[v][u]:
            dfs(u, cl)

for i in range(n):
    dfs(i, i)

# sort every component
buckets = [[] for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    buckets[color[i]].append(p[i])

for bucket in buckets:
    bucket.sort(reverse=True)

# build answer
print(*(buckets[color[i]].pop() for i in range(n)))
```

Comment: is their proof why we can swap any pair when they are in connected component?

Comment: your code is giving runtime error in most of testcases , can you please see to it.

Comment: @mss I've just go OK with minor fix in `a` read (it wasn't meant to work with windows-like endlines).

Comment: @mss Proof: let's leave spanning tree of every component. Now you can take any number that should go to leaf and move it there with consecutive swaps. Then it goes to it's place just forget about it (it doesn't interfere with next steps) and proceed to the next number.

Comment: Thanks for the proof.